# How to convert SQL Server datetime to UTC Json format?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column which is `datetime` in SQL Server, how can I get its Json based datetime format: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ"`?

By the way, I am using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Do you actually want to convert the date time from local to UTC or simply append `Z`?

Comment: Get the Json datetime format

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETUTCDATE(),'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ')
```

Output:
`2017-12-06T23:13:34Z`

`SELECT FORMAT(GETUTCDATE(),'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ')`

Output:
`2017-12-07T09:43:03.153Z`

Comment: That looks quite close, does it support format of `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ"`?

Comment: Try this:
`SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(datetime2, GETUTCDATE()),'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZZ')`

Comment: Thanks for that, I'v just updated your answer and accepted it. :)